# single command to reset ACLs and set owner

Tags: windows-server-2008, acl, file-permissions, ntfs

I'm trying to reset all file permissions and ACLs on a windows NTFS share. The following command should do that

```
icacls "D:\mydata" /T /Q /C /RESET
```

but I keep getting `Access is denied` errors for some subfolders.

So I went ahead, thinking I need to set admin permissions first:

```
icacls "D:\mydata" /grant administrator:F /T /C
```

however I still get `Access is denied`

**so here's my question:**
how I can remove `all` ACLS, `all` permissions, `all` owners, so that I can start assigning permissions and ACLS from scratch. I'd like to run one command that will reset things recursively, so that my admin account can then apply permissions again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take ownership of the object.
takeown from command line
if you have pro or similar version of windows - go to properties, security, advanced, owner, change owner (I hope that I haven't messed the way) and with few dozens of clicks you will get the object. Now you can add privilege to yourself.

Tricky part: What if an object is owned by someone (ex. TrustedInstaller or FancyVirus) and you have no access to the object but you wish to keep its current owner... In such a case - try unix as I wasn't able to find any answer for that (unless binary access to NTFS).

Good luck

Comment: I'd like to do all of this from the command line, could you provide the commands?

Answer (score -1):

```
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
$Folders = "\\server\share\"
$Folder = Get-ChildItem $Folders
FOREACH ($User in $Folder) {
    TAKEOWN /F $Folders$User /R /D Y
    $Username = Get-QADuser $User
    $Username = $Username.SamAccountName
    $FullPath = "$Folders" + "$Username"
    ICACLS ("$FullPath") /grant '"Domain Admins":(OI)(CI)F' /T
    ICACLS ("$FullPath") /grant ("$Username" + ':(OI)(CI)F') /T
}
```

http://tomandersonpro.net/ntfs-permissions-with-powershell/